# Why does ModBus require the RTS line?

Tags: modbus

i cannot figure this out by myself. What is the point of the RTS (direction) line in the RS485 ModBus communication?

There is no description about it on the internet, all the images in google only show the RX & TX lines but i know that RTS is also used.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only use of RTS in the context of RS485 based communications is so-called RS485 Transceiver Control (see for example the related [Docklight RS485 setting](http://docklight.de/manual/projectsettingsflowcontrol.htm)). In Microsoft Windows API for serial communications, this mode is called [RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Specifies that the RTS line will be high if bytes are available for transmission. After all buffered bytes have been sent, the RTS line will be low.

It has nothing to do with the 2-wire RS485 bus and the MODBUS application protocol used on such a bus. But some older RS232-to-RS485 (or USB-to-RS485) converters require the RTS signal to be set to high before transmitting any data, and reset it to low for receiving data.

Most standard RS485 interfaces and converters for PC can handle this switch between transmit and receive automatically, so they don't need the RTS at all. Just for example - For the popular MOXA brand this is called [ADDC (Automatic Data Direction Control](http://www.moxa.com/resource_file/857220091121341.pdf)).